# How to root Samsung J5 2017 (Android 7.0) on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: rooting, samsung, 7.0-nougat, linux

`Phone Name: Samsung J5 2017`

`Model number: SM-J530F`

`Build number: NRD90M.J530FXXU1AQI3`

I am using Ubuntu 17.10.

My question is, how could I root this phone using my PC? I have intermediate Linux shell knowledge and Android knowledge, however this is my first time attempting to root my device.

Many thanks, Thomas.